# Retrieve a city list for a country and state

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, mongodb, express.js

The code below is working properly but how do I make this code faster and more efficient. How do I perfect this code?

Let's assume I have 1000 country, state and city records in a mongodb collection. I want to retrieve all the city data by matching country id and state id. Please tell me the perfect way to code.

```
// @route   GET citylist/:countryid/:stateid
// @desc    get all the city from mongodb for countryid and stateid

router.get("/citylist/:countryid/:stateid", (req, res) => {
  const isValidCountryid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid( req.params.countryid);
  const isValidStateid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.stateid);

  if (isValidCountryid && isValidStateid) {
    CityModel.find({
      country_id: req.params.countryid,
      state_id: req.params.stateid
    })

      .then(cities => {
        if (!cities || !cities[0]) {
          return res.status(404).json({ msg: "City not found" });
        } else {
          res.json(cities);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(500).send(error));

  } else {
    res.json({ msg: "Country or State Id is not valid" });
  }
});
```

how to make this code highly fast, efficient, great time complexity and perfect way of code.

Comment: Please have a look at *Titling your question* in the [Help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and change your title accordingly! Namely, describe what your task is, not what you expect from the review.

Answer (score 4):

- Utilize the query object, this type of querying is more suitable there than as params.
- Use object destructuring.
- Dry your code, see how we're mapping over `[countryId, stateId]` to check the validity of the input. Ideally, you would have been using a module like `Joi` for that.
- Maintain a [happy path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path) and break out of the function early when erroring.
- Use `async/await` instead of `.then()`.
- Return a `400` when the input is invalid.
- User proper camelCase (in both the DB and the backend).
- Check the array length instead of checking the existence of the first element. So `if (arr.length)` not `if (arr[0])`. The reason for that is at some cases the first element of the array could be 'falsy' (such as `''` and `0`) which can be valid sometimes.
- When erroring, return an `error` field, not a `msg` one.
- Study javascript's array methods such as `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `every`. They will save your life more often than you thought.

```
router.get("/citylist", async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const { countryid, stateId } = req.query

    const validInput = [countryid, stateid].map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid).every(Boolean)
    if (!validInput) return res.status(400).json({ error: "Country or State Id is not valid" })

    const cities = await CityModel.find({ countryId, stateId })
    if (!cities || cities.length) return res.status(404).json({ error: "City not found" })

    res.json(cities);

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From a short review,

- Make sure that your database has an index: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/
- For the 404, since most countries have more than 1 city, I would return "Cities not found", I might even include the provided country and city in the return message so that the admin can be provided with an informative message
- I would have 2 different messages when the input data is bad, one for City, and one for country. Furthermore, for bad input data, I would use return code 400.
- It's very minor, but `CountryId` looks better than `countryid`
- Instead of `if (isValidCountryid && isValidStateid) {` I would check for bad data, and exit immediately, it makes for a lower cyclomatic complexity